# Why DNS recursive request named recursive?

Tags: domain-name-system

It is a request to perform a full conversion of the FQDN name to an IP address. Where is connection with the recursion?

Answer (score 2):

A recursive DNS query is when you ask a DNS resolver (such as Google public DNS) for a DNS entry, and it has to submit the exact same DNS query upstream to find the answer.

It's recursive in the sense that the exact same query is passed on, but in reality you only really get 1 level of recursion. You ask a resolver and the resolver may have to ask the authoritative servers.

Edit, seems i've got this a bit wrong. The recursive part is asking a root server, then the next level down, and so on until the resolver gets an answer to the query. Makes far more sense that what I understood it to mean...

Comment: Well in DNS recursion you do ask multiple DNS servers (starting with authoritatives for the root zone and Ltd) so it is not 'upstream'. What you describe is a forwarding resolver.

Comment: With Qname mimization, the recursive server does not propagate the exact same DNS query upstream anymore. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7816.txt

Answer (score 1):

A recursive DNS server implements DNS recursion. No more, no less.

DNS recursion is a process by which a DNS server asks as many questions as needed of authoritative DNS servers in order to satisfy a query. For more information, a book on DNS is recommended. (any further detail would be an essay on how DNS works)

Answer (score 0):

When a recursive DNS resolver receives a DNS query for a domain name, it doesn't have the answer readily available in its cache. Instead, it starts the resolution process by sending a query to the root DNS servers. These root servers respond with a referral to the appropriate top-level domain (TLD) servers responsible for that domain extension (e.g., .com, .org, .net).

The recursive resolver then sends another query to the TLD servers, which respond with a referral to the authoritative DNS servers responsible for the specific domain being queried. The recursive resolver follows these referrals, sending queries to the authoritative servers at each level until it receives the final answer—the IP address associated with the requested domain name.

The term "recursive" is used because the resolver recursively follows the chain of referrals from the root servers to the authoritative servers, essentially stepping through multiple levels of DNS hierarchy until it obtains the desired result. Each referral leads the resolver closer to the final resolution, with each step building upon the previous one.

This recursive resolution process allows DNS resolvers to handle complex DNS queries and resolve domain names even if they are not present in the resolver's cache. By recursively querying multiple DNS servers, the resolver can obtain the necessary information to complete the resolution and provide the IP address or other relevant data back to the client or application that initiated the DNS query.